# ZH Google Map extension causing 500 Internal Server Error after migration

Tags: joomla-3.x

I don't use Joomla myself but I did a host migration for a friend and the site, which uses Joomla, got a 500 Internal Server Error after the migration.
In order to make the site work, I just renamed the extension folder (so it would become inactive) and the error disappeared. However, as expected, the google map in the site stopped displaying.
I don't know much about Joomla, and since this isn't for me, I won't be spending lots of time to learn my way around the CMS. But I was wondering, perhaps someone has already had this same problem and could help out.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions to try (run a backup unsing Akeeba Backup or similar before doing any changes that can't easily be undone):

- upgrade Zh GoogleMap to the latest version (including any associated modules and plugins)
- temporarily rename the .htaccess file in the root folder to see if this makes any difference
- check file/folder permissions at System -> System Information -> Folder Permissions and fix any issues
- temporarily set System -> Global Configuration -> Server -> Error Reporting = Maximum to see if there is a more useful error message
- check logs for any relevant error messages